# Adding and substraction of 2 vectors using stack and queue in c++

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I have a problem with my C++ code. I need to add and substract 2 math vectors component by component using some header files but I can also implement some other functions. The thing is that my program doesn't have any errors but it's not executing... For example, if I have vector A(3,5) and B(1,7) the results should be: A+B=(4,12) and A-B=(2, -2). Any help could be very appreciated! This is my main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack_base.h"

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class App {

    public:

        Stack<T>  * stack;
        App(Stack<T> &stack) {
            this->stack = &stack;
        }

        T sum() {
            Stack<T> *tempStack = stack;
            T sum=0;
            int size = stack->getTopLevel();
            for(int i=0; i<=size; i++) {
                sum+=tempStack->peek();
                tempStack->pop();
                }
            return sum;
        }

        T substract() {
            Stack<T> tempStack = *stack;
            T substr=0;
            for(int i=0; i<=stack->getTopLevel(); i++) {
                substr-=tempStack.peek();
                tempStack.pop();
            }
            return substr;
        }
};

int main() {
    Stack<int> myStack;
    App<int> a(myStack);
    int values[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    int values1[7] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6};
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        myStack.push(values[i]);
        myStack.push(values1[i]);
    }
    cout<<"Sum of the elements is: "<<a.sum()<<endl;
    cout<<"Substraction of the elements is: "<<a.substract()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my stack_base.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NMAX 30 // pre-processing directive

template<typename T>
class Stack {

    private:

        // an array of NMAX dimension
        T stackArray[NMAX];
        /* the top of the stack, representing the INDEX of last element of the
        stackArray:0, 1, 2,....*/
        int topLevel;

    public:

        void push(T x) {
            //puts an element in the stack array

            //check if the stack array has the maximum dimension
            if (topLevel >= NMAX - 1) {
                cout<<"The stack is full: we have already NMAX elements!\n";
                //exit the function without making anything
                return;
            }
            /*add an element=> the index of the last element of the stack Array
            increases and put the value of the new element in the stack array*/
            stackArray[++topLevel] = x;
        }

        int isEmpty() {
            //returns 1, if topLevel>=0, meaning the stack array has elements
            // returns 0, otherwise
            return (topLevel < 0);
        }

        T pop() {
            // extracts and element from the stack array and returns the new top
            if (isEmpty()) {
                // the extraction is made only if the array is not empty
                cout<<"The stack is empty! \n";
                T x;
                return x;
            }
            // the topLevel decreases and the new top is changed
            return stackArray[--topLevel];
        }

        T peek() {
            // returns the top of the stack
            if (isEmpty()) {
                // the extraction is made only if the array is not empty
                cout<<"The stack is empty! \n";
                T x;
                return x;
            }
            return stackArray[topLevel];
        }

        void display() {
            for(int i=0;i<=topLevel;i++)
                cout<<stackArray[i];
        }

        bool search(T num) {
            for(int i=0; i<=topLevel;i++)
                if(num==stackArray[i])
                    return true;
            return false;
        }

        int getTopLevel(){
            return topLevel;
        }

        Stack() { // constructor
            topLevel = -1; // the stack is empty in the beginning
        }

        void sort(T s) {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                T x = Pop(s);
                sort(s);
                push(s, x);
            }
        }

        ~Stack() {} // destructor
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when you try to run the program? Does it crash? Do you get any output at all? If you enable more warnings when building your program, do the compiler tell you any warnings? Have you tried to [debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: If it's not executing it probably has at least one error. Your push/pop symmetry is broken, leading to undefined behaviour (think about what `pop` does when you have a one-element stack). Also think about which stack is getting emptied by `sum`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's stucked on a  black screen and it's not executing. I managed to do somehow the sum of all the elements of the vector but i can't do it component by component as I said

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. Please try to debug your own code by using a debugger to narrow down the problematic code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still can't solve the problem. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/